# How can i add markers dynamically to a rotated square in Tkinter factoring in zooming in or out?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create a map for a game using tkinter. I wanted to create a square. Rotate it by 45 degree and add coordinates to the square. The coordinates are for a 1200x1200 square which i have scaled to the size of the square. I managed to create the square and add markers to the rotated square  but I am unable to add markers dynamically when the cavas is zoomed in or zoomed out. I have tried different methods to find the scaling factor to apply but I am unable to create marker within the square in the correct location. Here is the correct marker on the rotated square [Marker on square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qkzR.png) created.

**Example Graph**

[image]

**Final expected result**

[image]

In the code below i am trying to add markers dynamically on right click. I want the markers to be correctly positioned inside the square, no matter the zoom-in or zoom-out. I tried calculating scaling factor and factor that in the calculation of marker position when zoom in or zoom out but i am unable to get that working.

```
import tkinter as tk
import math


# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Square with Markers")
root.geometry("800x800")

# Create a canvas widget
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=800)
canvas.update_idletasks()

canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, 1200, 1200))
canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", lambda event: on_button_press(event))
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda event: on_move_press(event))
canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: on_button_release(event))
canvas.bind("<MouseWheel>", lambda event: on_mouse_wheel(event))
canvas.bind("<Button-4>", lambda event: on_mouse_wheel(event))
canvas.bind("<Button-5>", lambda event: on_mouse_wheel(event))
canvas.bind("<Button-2>", lambda event: on_right_click(event))

canvas.pack()

drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "pan_x": 0, "pan_y": 0, "item": None}
zoom_factor = 1.0
scaling_factor = 1


def on_button_press(event):
    drag_data["x"] = event.x
    drag_data["y"] = event.y


def on_move_press(event):
    delta_x = event.x - drag_data["x"]
    delta_y = event.y - drag_data["y"]
    drag_data["x"] = event.x
    drag_data["y"] = event.y
    drag_data["pan_x"] += delta_x
    drag_data["pan_y"] += delta_y
    canvas.move("all", delta_x, delta_y)
    canvas.update()


def on_button_release(event):
    pass


# Zoom in or out based on the mouse wheel movement
def on_mouse_wheel(event):
    global zoom_factor, scaling_factor
    # Determine the direction of the mouse wheel scroll
    zoom_direction = 1.1 if event.delta > 0 else 0.9

    # Calculate the scaling factor based on the new zoom factor
    scaling_factor = zoom_direction ** abs(event.delta / 10)
    zoom_factor *= scaling_factor
    canvas.scale("all", event.x, event.y, scaling_factor, scaling_factor)
    # Calculate the delta values for panning based on the scaling factor
    delta_x = drag_data["pan_x"] * scaling_factor - drag_data["pan_x"]
    delta_y = drag_data["pan_y"] * scaling_factor - drag_data["pan_y"]

    # Update the pan values
    drag_data["pan_x"] += delta_x
    drag_data["pan_y"] += delta_y


def rotate_point(x, y, cx, cy, angle):
    # Rotate a point (x, y) around a center point (cx, cy) by the specified angle (in degrees)
    angle_rad = math.radians(angle)
    cos_val = math.cos(angle_rad)
    sin_val = math.sin(angle_rad)
    nx = cos_val * (x - cx) - sin_val * (y - cy) + cx
    ny = sin_val * (x - cx) + cos_val * (y - cy) + cy
    return nx, ny


def draw_square():
    canvas.update_idletasks()

    # Define the square coordinates
    square_coords = [(0, 0), (800, 0), (800, 800), (0, 800)]

    # Rotate the square by -135 degrees around its center
    square_center = (400, 400)
    rotated_square_coords = []
    # canvas.create_oval(400 - 5, 400 - 5, 400 + 5, 400 + 5, fill="blue")
    for coord in square_coords:
        x, y = coord
        nx, ny = rotate_point(x, y, square_center[0], square_center[1], 135)
        canvas.create_oval(nx - 5, ny - 5, nx + 5, ny + 5, fill="blue")
        rotated_square_coords.append((nx, ny))

    # Draw the rotated square on the canvas
    canvas.create_polygon(rotated_square_coords, outline='black', fill='white', tags="rotated_square")



def draw_marker():
    square_coords = canvas.coords("rotated_square")
    x_coords = square_coords[::2]
    y_coords = square_coords[1::2]
    min_x = min(x_coords)
    max_x = max(x_coords)
    # Get the coordinates of the two points you want to calculate the distance between
    x1, y1 = x_coords[0], y_coords[0]
    x2, y2 = x_coords[1], y_coords[1]

    # square_width = (max_x - min_x) * math.sqrt(2)
    square_width = math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
    min_y = min(y_coords)
    max_y = max(y_coords)
     # Get the coordinates of the two points for calculating the height
    x1, y1 = x_coords[1], y_coords[1]
    x2, y2 = x_coords[2], y_coords[2]

    square_height = math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
    x_center = sum(x_coords) / len(x_coords)
    y_center = sum(y_coords) / len(y_coords)

    # Define the marker coordinates (normal coordinates)
    marker_coords = [ (788, 496),(600,600)]  # (600,600), (969, 1094), (957, 776), (894, 534), (295, 5), (114, 385), (169, 749),

    # Convert normal coordinates to pixel coordinates and rotate around the center
    pixel_coords = []
    for coord in marker_coords:
        x, y = coord
        pixel_x = x * 800 // 1200
        pixel_y = 800 - y * 800 // 1200  # Reverse the y-axis direction
        debug(pixel_x, pixel_y, x_center, y_center)
        rotated_x, rotated_y = rotate_point(pixel_x, pixel_y, x_center, y_center, 135)
        pixel_coords.append((rotated_x, rotated_y))

    # Draw the rotated markers on the canvas
    marker_radius = 5
    for coord in pixel_coords:
        x, y = coord
        canvas.create_oval(x - marker_radius, y - marker_radius, x + marker_radius, y + marker_radius, fill='red')


def on_right_click(event):
    debug("right clicked")
    square_coords = canvas.coords("rotated_square")
    x_coords = square_coords[::2]
    y_coords = square_coords[1::2]

    # Calculate the center of the square
    cx = sum(x_coords) / len(x_coords)
    cy = sum(y_coords) / len(y_coords)

    # Get the coordinates of the two points you want to calculate the distance between
    x1, y1 = x_coords[0], y_coords[0]
    x2, y2 = x_coords[1], y_coords[1]

    square_width = math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)

    # Get the coordinates of the two points for calculating the height
    x1, y1 = x_coords[1], y_coords[1]
    x2, y2 = x_coords[2], y_coords[2]

    square_height = math.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)

    marker_coords = [(788, 496), (600, 600)]

    canvas_width = canvas.winfo_width()
    canvas_height = canvas.winfo_height()

    scaling_factor_x = canvas_width / square_width
    scaling_factor_y = canvas_height / square_height

    scaled_square_width = square_width * scaling_factor_x
    scaled_square_height = square_height * scaling_factor_y

    for x, y in marker_coords:
        # Convert the normal coordinates to pixel coordinates
        pixel_x = x * scaled_square_width / 1200
        pixel_y = canvas_height - y * scaled_square_height / 1200  # Reverse the y-axis direction

        # Calculate the rotated positions around the center of the square
        rotated_x, rotated_y = rotate_point(pixel_x, pixel_y, cx * scaling_factor_x, cy * scaling_factor_y, 135)

        # Adjust the marker coordinates based on the scaling factor
        scaled_rotated_x = rotated_x * (1 / scaling_factor_x)
        scaled_rotated_y = rotated_y * (1 / scaling_factor_y)

        # Calculate the marker position relative to the canvas
        mx = scaled_rotated_x
        my = scaled_rotated_y

        marker_size = 5
        canvas.create_oval(mx - marker_size, my - marker_size,
                           mx + marker_size, my + marker_size, fill='blue')




# Call the function to draw the square with markers
draw_square()
draw_marker()

# Start the Tkinter event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to make a map, you can use the [`tkintermapview`](https://pypi.org/project/tkintermapview/) library that will allow you to easily use **Google Maps API**.

If you are looking for a fast and easy way to display the world map that is.
If your goal is to make it yourself from the ground up for learning purposes this won't teach you that much though.

Here is an example of how you could implement `tkintermapview`.

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkintermapview import TkinterMapView

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 500

root = Tk()
root.geometry(f"{WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}")

# create map
map_view = TkinterMapView(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
map_view.pack()

# google normal tile server
map_view.set_tile_server("https://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&s=Ga", max_zoom=40)

# choose where to search for
map_view.set_address("Paris France", marker=True)

root.mainloop()
```

I hope this helps !

Comment: I am not looking to create a google map view but more of a graph style plotting for a game.